# blockchain - strange problem

Tags: blockchain, client, error

I have Windows 7 and i’m using the bitcoin-qt client v0.8.6-beta.

Last night i tried to open up the client – but there was a message that said i had some issues with the blockchain. Which is weird, i never had any problem before so i closed it and reopened the client.

Then suddenly the blockchain started to download it self from the very beginning (!) backlog of like 260 weeks! But the old (and already downloaded) blockchain is still on my pc – so why dosen’t the client recognise it?

The bitcoins are still inside the wallet – or at least it shows them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhabs your [bitcoin datadir](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) has moved. Try to start you client with the path to you folder containing the blockchain:

```
bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir=
```

Another posibility, the client is just reindexing the blockchain, not downloading. You can check this if you hover over the progressbar and look at the text.

Comment: Thank u! The second one it was, the "reindexing". Don't know why it did that. But i also updated now to a newer client version. Thank you sir!